# Combining values in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to create a cronjob for renewal lets encrypt certificates.
The final command should looks like this:

```
certbot certonly --no-eff-email -m my@mail.com --redirect --agree-tos --non-interactive --standalone -d mydomain.com -d www.mydomain.com -d domain1.mydomain.com -d domain1a.mydomain.com -d domain2.mydomain.com -d domain2a.mydomain.com
```

I have the following variables:

```
nginx:
  vhost:
    - name: mydomain.com
      server_name:
        - mydomain.com
        - www.mydomain.com
      ...
      ...
    - name: domain1.mydomain.com
      server_name:
        - domain1.mydomain.com
        - domain1a.mydomain.com
      ...
      ...
    - name: domain2.mydomain.com
      server_name:
        - domain2.mydomain.com
        - domain2a.mydomain.com
      ...
      ...
      ...
```

How can I get this values from `nginx.vhost.server_name` of each `vhost` in one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "cerbot -d {{ server_names }}"
      vars:
        server_names: "{{ nginx.vhost|map(attribute='server_name')|flatten|join(' -d ') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: cerbot -d mydomain.com -d www.mydomain.com -d domain1.mydomain.com -d domain1a.mydomain.com -d domain2.mydomain.com -d domain2a.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example; I'm using a `debug` task instead of, say, a `command` task, because I don't want to actually run anything on my computer, but this should demonstrate the technique:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    nginx:
      vhost:
        - name: mydomain.com
          server_name:
            - mydomain.com
            - www.mydomain.com
        - name: domain1.mydomain.com
          server_name:
            - domain1.mydomain.com
            - domain1a.mydomain.com
        - name: domain2.mydomain.com
          server_name:
            - domain2.mydomain.com
            - domain2a.mydomain.com
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "cerbot {% for name in server_names %}-d {{name}} {%endfor%}"
      vars:
        server_names: "{{ nginx.vhost|map(attribute='server_name')|flatten }}"
```

We use the `map` filter to extract the value of `server_name` from each item in the `nginx.vhost` list, and then pass the result to `flatten` to get a single list instead of a list of lists.

Running the above will generate as output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "cerbot -d mydomain.com -d www.mydomain.com -d domain1.mydomain.com -d domain1a.mydomain.com -d domain2.mydomain.com -d domain2a.mydomain.com "
}
```